# MPAndroidChart conditional dataset color

Tags: android, charts, colors, mpandroidchart

Hello folks: I am wondering if there is a better way to conditional coloring bars using MPAndroidChart. My solution is create a conditional array of colors as follows:

```
private void setDataColored(List<String> labels, List<Float> values) {

    final int greenColor = Color.parseColor("#66bb6a");
    final int redColor = Color.parseColor("#ef5350");
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int pos = 0; pos < values.size(); pos++) {
        Float value = values.get(pos);
        entries.add(new BarEntry(Math.abs(value), pos));
        colors.add(value >= 0 ? greenColor : redColor);
    }

    BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "Values");
    dataset.setColors(colors);

    ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<BarDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(dataset);

    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataSets);
    data.setDrawValues(true);

    mChart.setData(data);
}
```

I am worry about performance, since I need to create this `colors` array. Derived problem is Legend: I cant visualize properly specifying red and green color meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I see the documentation [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Colors)

We can sure apply the different colors to the bar based on our dynamic condition. Now let's see your problem you have array of float values that need to match with the color array. If the value in negative it should represent with the RED and the positive should display into the green.

Instead of colors array you can have LineDataSet for example see below :

```
final int greenColor = R.color.green;
final int redColor = R.color.Red;    
ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
for (int pos = 0; pos < values.size(); pos++) 
{
        Float value = values.get(pos);
        entries.add(new BarEntry(Math.abs(value), pos));
        colors.add(value >= 0 ? greenColor : redColor);
}

LineDataSet setComp1 = new LineDataSet(entries, "Company 1");
// sets colors for the dataset, resolution of the resource name to a "real" color is done internally
setComp1.setColors(colors, Context);
```

Comment: This is a bit different. But essencially the same

Comment: Another way may be extends the BarDataset class and override the getColor(..) method I guess that is different way :)

Comment: How to set default background color to the dataset. Like we set color to the piechart data and the remaining part should be the default color